# Apply and lambdas in Scala

Tags: scala, lambda, apply

I have the following piece of code

```
scala> val builder = new StringBuilder("foo bar baz ")
builder: StringBuilder = foo bar baz

scala> (0 until 5) foreach { builder.append("!") }

scala> builder.toString
res15: String = foo bar baz !
```

I guess that in reality something like

```
(0 until 5) foreach builder.append("!").apply
```

happens. Can anyone explain to me why that happens or if I'm wrong what really happens?

Comment: Damn, I was just writing an answer, when I realized, that in this scenario `(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply }`  behaves differently from `(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply(_) }`, which I can't explain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what's happening I used my small tool [scala-to-java](https://github.com/Aivean/scala-to-java).

Your code transpiled to Java looks like this:

```
public final class _$$anon$1 {
  private final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("foo bar baz ");

  private StringBuilder builder() {
    return this.builder;
  }

  {
    RichInt$.MODULE$.until$extension0(Predef$.MODULE$.intWrapper(0), 5).foreach((Function1<Object, Object>)this.builder().append("!"));
    this.builder().toString();
  }
}
```

As you can see, result of the `builder.append("!")`, which is also `StringBuilder` is simply cast to `Function1` and used as a function argument in foreach.

Apparently, `StringBuilder` is indeed a function, if you check it's type hierarchy:

- StringBuilder (scala.collection.mutable)
- AbstractSeq (scala.collection.mutable)
- AbstractSeq (scala.collection)
- Seq (scala.collection)
- PartialFunction (scala)
- Function1 (scala)

As a conclusion:

- You can use any `StringBuilder` as an function or partial function from `Int` to `Char`
- In your case, `append` is evaluated only once and it's result (`StringBuilder`) is used as a function.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just switched from Kotlin to Scala and what was a function in Kotlin in Scala became just a block of code which by coincidence returns a function of appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` expects a function from (in your case) `Int => Unit` you provide `() => StringBuilder`. However, as `StringBuilder` is a collection, it's 'apply' function to retrieve a the Character at a specific index is selected as the function to apply in the foreach loop.

You can fix your code with:

```
(0 until 5) foreach { _ => builder.append("!")}
```