# Unexpected behavior of StringBuilder in foreach

Tags: scala, foreach

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800221/apply-and-lambdas-in-scala) I stumbled upon a behavior I could not explain.

Coming from:

```
val builder = new StringBuilder("foo bar baz ")

(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!") }

builder.toString -> res1: String = foo bar baz !
```

The issue seemed clear, the function provided to the foreach was missing the Int argument, so `StringBuilder.apply` got executed. But that does not really explain why it appends the '!' only once. So I got to experimenting..

I would have expected the following six statements to be equivalent, but the resulting Strings differ:

```
(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!") }               -> res1: String = foo bar baz !
(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!")(_) }            -> res1: String = foo bar baz !!!!
(0 until 4) foreach { i => builder.append("!")(i) }       -> res1: String = foo bar baz !!!!

(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply }         -> res1: String = foo bar baz !
(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply(_) }      -> res1: String = foo bar baz !!!!
(0 until 4) foreach { i => builder.append("!").apply(i) } -> res1: String = foo bar baz !!!!
```

So the statements are obviously not equivalent. Can somebody explain the difference?

Comment: `a.b.c(_)` is sugar for `x => a.b.c(x)` (by SLS 6.23.1). `a.b.c _` is sugar for `val tmp = a.b; tmp.c _` (by SLS 6.26.5). In the former case `a.b` is evaluated over and over again, in the latter case only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's label them:

- `A` -  `(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply }`
- `B` -  `(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply(_) }`
- `C` -  `(0 until 4) foreach { i => builder.append("!").apply(i) }`

At first glance it is confusing, because it appears they should all be equivalent to each other. Let's look at `C` first. If we look at it as a `Function1`, it should be clear enough that `builder.append("!")` is evaluated with each invocation.

```
val C = new Function1[Int, StringBuilder] {
    def apply(i: Int): StringBuilder = builder.append("!").apply(i)
}
```

For each element in `(0 to 4)`, `C` is called, which re-evaluates `builder.append("!")` on each invocation.

The important step to understanding this is that `B` is syntactic sugar for `C`, and *not* `A`. Using the underscore in `apply(_)` tells the compiler to create a *new* anonymous function `i => builder.append("!").apply(i)`. We might not necessarily expect this because `builder.append("!").apply` can be a function in it's own right, if eta-expanded. The compiler appears to prefer creating a new anonymous function, that simply wraps `builder.append("!").apply`, rather than eta-expanding it.

From the [SLS 6.23.1 - Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions)

> An expression e of syntactic category Expr binds an underscore section u, if the following two conditions hold: (1) e properly contains u, and (2) there is no other expression of syntactic category Expr which is properly contained in e and which itself properly contains u.

So `builder.append("!").apply(_)` properly contains the underscore, so the underscore syntax can applies for the anonymous function, and it becomes `i => builder.append("!").apply(i)`, like `C`.

Compare this to:

```
(0 until 4) foreach { builder.append("!").apply _ }
```

Here, the underscore is not properly contained in the expression, so the underscore syntax does not immediately apply as `builder.append("!").apply _` can also mean eta-expansion. In this case, eta-expansion comes first, which will be equivalent to `A`.

For `A`, it is `builder.append("!").apply` is implicitly eta-expanded to a function, which will only evaluate `builder.append("!")` once. e.g. it is something *like*:

```
val A = new Function1[Int, Char] {
    private val a = builder.append("!")

    // append is not called on subsequent apply calls
    def apply(i: Int): Char = a.apply(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder` extends `(Int => Char)`, and therefore `builder.append("!")`, which returns a `StringBuilder`, is a valid *function* argument to `foreach`. The first line is therefore equivalent as if you wrote:

```
val f: Int => Char = builder.append("!").asInstanceOf[Int => Char] // appends "!" once
(0 until 4).foreach(f) // fetches the 0th to 3rd chars in the string builder, and does nothing with them
```

All the lines that append !!!! actually create a new anonymous function `i => builder.append("!").apply(i)`, and are therefore equivalent to

```
val f: Int => Char = (i: Int) => builder.append("!").apply(i)
(0 until 4).foreach(f) // appends 4 times (and fetches the 0th to 3rd chars in the string builder, and does nothing with them)
```

As for your fourth line, it's weirder IMO. In that case, you are trying to read a "field" `apply` in `builder.append("!")`. But `apply` is a method `(Int)Char`, and the expected type (as determined by the param type of `foreach`) is `Int => ?`. So there *is* a way to lift the method `apply(Int)Char` as an `Int => ?`, which is to create a lambda that will call the method. But in this case, since you're trying to read `apply` as field, initially, it means that the `this` of `.apply` should be evaluated *once* to be stored as a capture for the `this` parameter of the method call, giving something equivalent to this:

```
val this$1: StringBuilder = builder.append("!") // appends "!" once
val f: Int => Char = (i: Int) => this$1.apply(i)
(0 until 4).foreach(f) // fetches the 0th to 3rd chars in the string builder, and does nothing with them
```