# define function in scala, difference between FunctionName and FunctionName(_)

Tags: scala

I try to define a recursive function in Scala with following code:

```
object Factorial {
    val almostFactorial = (f: Int => Int) => (n: Int) => if(n == 0) 1 else n * f(n - 1)
    val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial(factorial)
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(factorial(5))
    }
}
```

The above code compiles but runs with exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But if I change

```
val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial(factorial)
```

into

```
val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial(factorial(_))
```

Then it runs well.

What's the difference between these two declaration, and why does the first one cause that exception?

Comment: That's pretty similar to a problem I had. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801342/589273) helped me out.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg I'm still confused with what happened in my case, the error seems that the `factorial` is null, why will it be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. implementation: Why this causes a null Pointer Exception

```
val factorial: Int => Int = {
  println(s"Before recursive def: $factorial")
  almostFactorial(factorial)
}
```

Running this code shows you that in the recursive definition `factorial` is `null`. The answer lies in the implementation of Scala Function values as objects in the JVM.
As the default value for objects is null and factorial is not yet initialised when assigned to `val factorial : Int => Int` is `null`.

As the object is created `val`s are instantly evaluated. So the compiler falls back to the default value.

## 2. implementation: Why this works

By using the `fun _` syntax you change the implementation to a function to a `partial applied function`. Which will be evaluated when you provide an Int. So it will be not evaluated the same time the val would be evaluated.

So this function will be evalutaed with invocation of the main method. Which will be called when on runs the program.

So adding some print statements (bad style, don't do in prodcution code) will help you to find out the value of the vals at object creation time:

```
  val factorial: Int => Int = {
    println(s"Before recursive def: $factorial")
    val partialFactorial = factorial(_)
    println(partialFactorial)
    almostFactorial(partialFactorial)
}
```

Running the second implementation you will then get this output

```
Before recursive def: null
<function1> <- Partial applied factorial(_)
120
```

## Extended Example: Why using a partial applied function will not automatically protect you here

So the function is `null` at object creation. If you would provide the value directly in the implementation of the val to the partial applied function as in this example:

```
  val factorial: Int => Int = {
    println(s"Before recursive def: $factorial")
    val partialFactorial = factorial(_)
    println(partialFactorial)
    println(partialFactorial(2)) // here we will again cause a null pointer exception
    almostFactorial(partialFactorial)
  }
```

you end up with a null pointer exception again:

```
$scala Factorial

Before recursive def: null
<function1>
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Factorial$$anonfun$1.apply$mcII$sp(Example.scala:5)s
```

Comment: I also find that if I declare `lazy val factorial` instead of `val factorial`, or declare `def factorial` instead of `val factorial`, it will cause `stack over flow` error at runtime, what happened in that case?

Comment: with `def` you really run in an infinite loop : `factorial` will `call factorial` which will `call factorial` and so on.

Comment: with `lazy val` roughly the same happens.

Answer (score 2):

You are using higher-order functions here. In that case underscore (_) acts as placeholder. So actually your code:

```
val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial(factorial(_))
```

Actually can be represented as:

```
val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial( x => factorial(x) )
```

**UPD:**

As @Clashsoft added his comment I figured out what happened.

When you define your function as:

```
val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial(factorial)
```

You're pointing to exact the same instance of *factorial* over and over. But when you define your function as:

```
val factorial: Int => Int = almostFactorial(factorial(_))
```

Scala create *another anonymous function* which contains your *factorial*. So it not pointing on itself directly.

Comment: thanks. I re-edit the question, I also want to know why does the first one cause that exception.

Comment: The exception is raised because the `factorial` variable references itself. This would not actually be possible in Java, but Scala somehow allows this. Because the val is not initialized yet when it is being initialized (duh), you effectively pass `null` to the function.

Comment: @Clashsoft So this is related with strict evaluation? Without underscore, `factorial` directly references itself which makes it initialized with un-initialized value, while with underscore, it is wrapped in another anonymous function which makes it initialized with that expression. Sorry I don't know what I spoke. I think I still miss some details. what exactly happens with that line of code?

Comment: another answer is a little bit more concrete, both of your answers are good, and I can only select one, so I up vote your answer.